# what's the difference between including a mixin with () and without () in sass?

Tags: sass, mixins

I am creating a CSS library and I was using a `mixin` in my sass code, I was wondering what's the difference between `@include btn` and `@include btn()` in the example below? because they have the same result...

```
//index.scss
@mixin btn($bg-color: red) {
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
border: 0;
background: $bg-color;
}
//first type
.btn {
@include btn();
}

//second type
.btn {
@include btn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Sass, the difference between `@include btn` and `@include btn()` lies in the way arguments are passed to the mixin.

When you use `@include btn;`, you are simply including the mixin without any arguments. This means it will use the default values defined within the mixin, which in this case is `red` for the background color.

On the other hand, when you use `@include btn();`, you are explicitly calling the mixin with empty parentheses. This allows you to override the default values and pass different arguments if needed. In your example, since you are not passing any arguments, it will still use the default value of `red` for the background color.

So in your specific case, both `@include btn` and `@include btn();` will have the same result because you are not passing any arguments and the default value of `red` will be used. However, using `@include btn();` provides more flexibility in case you want to pass different arguments in the future.